# "Now" for emphasis

Tags: sentence-construction

I have the following sentence:

> Mark, come out of the room **right now**.

Can I transform it into the next one without losing the meaning?

> Mark, come out of the room. **Now!**

If there is a difference in the meaning between "now" in the first sentence of the first version and "now" in the second sentence of the second version, please explain it.

I guess "right now" is similar to "Now!" in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions mean exactly the same; the second is fine as a representation of natural speech. The speaker might well add "Now!" after a pause if the order wasn't immediately obeyed.